# Correct display of DICOM images ITK-VTK (images too dark)

Tags: c++, vtk, dicom, itk, medical

I read dicom images with ITK using itk::ImageSeriesReader and itk::GDCMImageIO after reading i flip the images with itk::FlipImageFilter (to get right orientation of the images) and convert the itkImageData to vtkImageData using itk::ImageToVTKImageFilter. I visualization images with VTK using vtkResliceImageViewer in QVTKWidget2. 
I set:

```
 (vtkResliceImageViewer)m_imageViewer[i]->SetColorWindow(windowWidthTAGvalue[0028|1051]);
 (vtkResliceImageViewer)m_imageViewer[i]->SetColorLevel(windowCenterTAGvalue[0028|1050]);
```

and i set following blac&white LookUpTable:

```
   vtkLookupTable* lutbw = vtkLookupTable::New();
    lutbw->SetTableRange(0,1000);
    lutbw->SetSaturationRange(0,0);
    lutbw->SetHueRange(0,0);
    lutbw->SetValueRange(0,1);
    lutbw->Build();
```

And images shown into my software compared with the same images shown into other software are much darker, i can not get the same effect as other DICOM viewers

My software images are right other software image is left also when i use some other LookUpTable in this example Flow i can not get the same effect (2nd row images) my image on right is much darker then other.

[image: ImageCompare]

What i am missing why my images are darker what can i do? i was research a lot into dicom and ikt/vtk can not find good solution any help is appreciate.

Comment: Two common reasons for too dark images are: 1) (lack of) gamma correction, and 2) alpha blending.
Looking at the images on the right I would bet on alpha blending: your alpha is set to the intensity, and to zero for the light blue background. Try disabling alpha blending, if you can.

Comment: i tried changing value of  alpha blending setting to 0/1, cant see any effect

Comment: My spontaneous thought about the difference is unused values in the output image. Opening the top-right image in an image editor shows this is the case. An image on screen is in the range 0-255 for black-white. You are only using 0-180ish. What you need is to scale it to 0-255. It seems the reference on the left is also cutting some of the higher values, effectively scaling your image's lower 0-100, say, into 0-255.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the values for Rescale Slope (0028,1053) and Rescale Intercept(0028,1052) and apply the Modality LUT transformation before applying the Window level. 
Your dataset may have VOI LUT Function (0028,1056) attribute value of "SIGMOID" instead of "LINEAR".

Comment: I spend few days with this problem, can you give me more informations or directions how to solve this, i tried setting Rescale Slope (0028,1053) and Rescale Intercept(0028,1052) and apply to each pixel using this equation:x     is the stored pixel value
    m     is the value of Rescale Slope (0028,1053)
    b     is the value of Rescale Intercept (0028,1052)
    y     is the rescaled, meaningful value
then
    y = (m * x) + b ; but i dont get any good result. :/

Comment: I need more information from the DICOM files to give you farther suggestions. I am basically looking for information related to Modality LUT Module and VOI LUT Module. 
There are different ways to encode the modality LUT transformation other than the linear transformation (LUT data encoded under the Modality LUT sequence). Also, a dataset may have multiple VOI LUTs (multiple views) and it can be linear or LUT data is encoded under VOI LUT Sequence. 
Is it possible for you to share your DICOM file?

Comment: Sure here is download link from dropbox check it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vyxrmgxbuxysjnp/Dicom%20Example.rar?dl=0

Comment: I reviewed your DICOM files. Pixel Representation tag (0028,0103) has “1” as value. That means pixel data is encoded as signed pixel. Also, there is no value stored for VOI LUT and Modality LUT will not change the stored pixel value.

Comment: So what is the problem? maybe i got some problem with the library i use maybe it is some VTK problem/bug/malfunction :/

Answer (score 2):

I extracted the image data from one of your DICOM file (brain_009.dcm) and looked at the histogram of the image data. It looks like, the minimum value stored in the image is 0 and maximum value is 960 regardless of interpreting the data is signed or unsigned. Also, the Window Width (0028:1051) has an invalid value of “0” and you cannot use that for displaying the image.
So your default display could set the Window Width to 960 and Window Center to half the window width plus the minimum value.

Comment: The problem is not just with this image data also happens to other examples too, i calculate the window width and the center as you said, this is some problem with the library i use to display the images(VTK). Really appreciate your support mate thanks!

Comment: Look on the image the problem is for same value for WW/WL the image is darker into my software :/