# vtkResliceImageViewer display incorrect (too dark) dicom image

Tags: c++, image-processing, vtk, dicom, itk

I am using vtkResliceImageViewer vtk library class to display `DICOM files`. Images are too dark. I don't know if I use it wrong way or it's a bug (there was similar unresolved problem posted before: [Correct display of DICOM images ITK-VTK (images too dark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731367/correct-display-of-dicom-images-itk-vtk-images-too-dark)).

I am using custom `DICOM` data reader and I'm sure data is ok. `vtkImageViewer2` class displays it correctly. I'am sure that this is not issue connected to `Modality LUT`, `Rescale Slope/Intercept`, `VOI LUT` and `window center/width` (values are fine).

I attach basic code example producing two images. `Window center = 40` and `width = 400` are hardcoded and are 100% proper for tested image. Render window with red background displays image using `vtkImageViewer2` class and it's perfectly fine. Render window with green background display image using `vtkResliceImageViewer` and it's too dark. When I set `WindowLevel to -40` instead of 40 it's look close to the proper displayed image.

Both clases use `vtkImageMapToWindowLevelColors` to apply window transformation. I've tried using `SetOutputFormatToLuminance()` and `PassAlphaToOutputOff()` methods of that class but this didn't help.

Does somebody have same problem and resolved it some way?

[image]

```
SeriesDataReader dataReader;
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> data = dataReader.ReadSeriesData();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->SetSize(900, 900);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->SetBackground(0, 1, 0);
renderer->ResetCamera();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);


vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow2->SetSize(900, 900);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer2->SetBackground(1, 0, 0);
renderer2->ResetCamera();
renderWindow2->AddRenderer(renderer2);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor2->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow2);
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
imageViewer->SetInputData(data);
imageViewer->SetColorLevel(40.0);
imageViewer->SetColorWindow(400.0);
imageViewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor2);
imageViewer->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow2);
imageViewer->SetRenderer(renderer2);
imageViewer->Render();
imageViewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera();
imageViewer->Render();


vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkResliceImageViewer> resliceImageViewer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkResliceImageViewer>::New();
resliceImageViewer->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
resliceImageViewer->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
resliceImageViewer->SetSliceOrientationToXY();
resliceImageViewer->SetRenderer(renderer);
resliceImageViewer->SetInputData(data);
resliceImageViewer->SetSliceOrientation(2);
resliceImageViewer->SetResliceModeToAxisAligned();
resliceImageViewer->SetColorLevel(40.0);
resliceImageViewer->SetColorWindow(400.0);
resliceImageViewer->SetResliceMode(0);
resliceImageViewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera();
resliceImageViewer->Render();


imageViewer->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
renderWindowInteractor2->Initialize();
imageViewer->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
renderWindowInteractor2->Start();

resliceImageViewer->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
resliceImageViewer->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

Comment: Have you try to see if an alpha channel on color is not lost during process??

Comment: Two common reasons for too dark images are: 1) (lack of) gamma correction, and 2) alpha blending. Looking at the images on the right I would bet on alpha blending: your alpha is set to the intensity, and to zero for the light blue background. Try disabling alpha blending, if you can

Comment: For vtkImageData I set: AllocateScalars(VTK_DOUBLE, 1). Image data is composed from one component double values per pixel so there is no alpha channel. Same data displays properly in vtkImageViewer2.

Comment: have you tried using `vtkImagePlanWidget` and play around with the `SetWindowLevel` method?

Comment: `vtkImagePlaneWidget` also do not proper display images with window center/width transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that issue. For proper display of images with wl/ww transformation comment out or remove line 327 in void vtkResliceImageViewer::InstallPipeline() function.

Line 327: `this->WindowLevel->SetLookupTable(this->GetLookupTable());`